# Can I change isDebugEnabled property runtime?

Tags: java, logging, runtime, logback

I am using ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext and ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger and I am trying to change log levels at runtime, and also want to change isDebugEnabled property to true so that I can debug the specific logs.
Is it possible to change it runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change log level for each logger or for the root (see http://logback.qos.ch/manual/architecture.html more)

If you need to change for all logs:

```
Logger root = (Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
root.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```

Comment: Yes, I did change log level for all loggers. But some logs are depends on the DEBUG mode only when i.e. logger.isDebugEnabled() is true. Here I am getting it false, thats why I need the way to change iSdegubEnabled to true.

Comment: `((Logger) LOGGER).setLevel(Level.INFO); 
((Logger) LOGGER).isDebugEnabled(); -- returns false `
`((Logger) LOGGER).setLevel(Level.DEBUG); 
((Logger) LOGGER).isDebugEnabled(); -- returns true`

Comment: Thanks Natalia, It is working fine I had some other configuration issue. After setting DEBUG Level it is returning true. :)